# Select odd numbers and does not contain special characters

Tags: mysql, sql

This is Table `WWE` :

```
    |**Col A**  | **Col B** |
   -+-----------+-----------+-    
    | Hello     | 9%15A     |    
    | World     | 2*10      |    
    | Cat       | 12        |    
    | Dog       | 13        |
```

`Col B` is `Varchar (100)`

How do I select all rows consist of ODD NUMBERS ONLY and does not contain '%' or '*' or alphabets??

I know how to get ODD NUMBERS : `colB % 2 <> 0`

But I don't know how to EXCLUDE the special characters and to calculate the number as NUMBER since they're stored in VARCHAR

For example in this table, the output will be

```
| Dog | 13 |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check both conditions with a single regular expression:

```
SELECT * FROM WWE WHERE colB REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]*[13579]$';
```

Which could be read as:

> *Starts with a digit, followed by any number of digits and finishing with any one of these characters (1,3,5,7)*

For this sample data

```
    |**Col A**  | **Col B** |
   -+-----------+-----------+-    
    | Hello     | 9%15A     |    
    | World     | 2*10      |    
    | Cat       | 12        |    
    | Dog       | 13        |
```

Returns

```
    |**Col A**  | **Col B** |
   -+-----------+-----------+-      
    | Dog       | 13        |
```

*Updated* to account for single digits, thanks to @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: what is 13579 for?

Comment: it's a way to guarantee that it's an odd number, odd numbers end up in an odd digit

Comment: Okay, understandable. can it usable for number like this 235

Comment: It should be `'^[[:digit:]]*[13579]$'` though to allow for single-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

USE `REGEXP` if you need only numeric result:

```
SELECT * FROM WWE WHERE colB REGEXP '[0-9]' AND colB mod 2 = 1
```

Comment: it still output data with special characters and alphabets

Comment: add a bracket for odd number check and try.

Comment: same output hmm

Comment: try using mod instead of %. which part is not working for you? getting odd number or getting numeric result? I am using MySQL server version: 5.5 and it works fine here. what version do u work?

Answer (score 1):

Or use the ISNUMERIC function

```
SELECT * FROM WWE WHERE ISNUMERIC(colB) = 1 AND colB % 2 <> 0
```

Comment: What is the equivalent for ISNUMERIC in mysql?

Comment: Didn't noticed it was for MySQL, I guess you will have to go with the Regex.

Comment: it's fine :) Thank you!